# Free DHCP server for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, dhcp

Are there any (good) free DHCP servers for Windows XP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I will not comment on running server services on XP.*

*I will not comment on running server services on XP.*

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/

Answer (score 3):

There's an open-source solution here: [**http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/)

Another, not so open: [**http://www.softcab.com/dhcp-server/index.php**](http://www.softcab.com/dhcp-server/index.php)

...but to tell you the truth, I'd let my router do this for me.  I'd recommend running your services under Linux, specially if you think you're going to have more **"Are there any (good) free 'x' servers?"** questions (no offense).

Answer (score 2):

Use a linksys/cicso router. :)

Comment: I'm looking for a software solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Free DHCP Server for Windows](http://ruttkamp.gmxhome.de/dhcpsrv/dhcpsrv.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP [Internet Connection Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) (ICS)?

Comment: Windows ICS, and DHCP server associated with it are at best avoided.